# How to exclude css files from auto formatting in IntelliJ

Tags: css, intellij-idea, formatting, code-formatting

We're using the auto formatting feature of IntelliJ to format our code whenever a commit to git is made.

The formatting works well for us except for our designer who's not happy with the way how IntelliJ formats his CSS files. Is there a way to deactivate auto formatting for certain file types?

Comment: Stupid question, what does the CSS format look like after being auto formatted?

Comment: I think we don't have to justify ourselves why we don't like the format.

Comment: Who said I wanted a justification? I was curious.

Comment: Then don't call the question stupid!

Comment: My question was stupid, not yours. It's a phrase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since IDEA 13 it is possible to deactivate formatting with

`/* @formatter:off */`

and reactivate with

`/* @formatter:on */`

But you need to enable that first in
Settings -> Code Style -> General -> Formatter Control

Later versions of IntelliJ offer the setting in
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Formatter

Answer (score 5):

You can also right-click on a file and choose "Mark as Plain Text". When reformatting (Ctrl+Alt+L) these files are then excluded.

This also works in IntelliJ 12.